# Show the eigenvalues of a square matrix are between zero and one.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be two positive definite matrices of orders $n$ and $d,$ respectively. Let $X$ be a matrix of type $(n,d)$ ($n$ rows and $d$ columns).

> Is it true that $A^{-1} X B^{-1} X^\intercal$ have eigenvalues between zero and one?

I am unsure if the result holds with this generality, so I am giving more context below.

This problem arises in the study of "contingency tables" (i.e. statistics) where $X$ is a design matrix of zeros and ones, where each row represents an observation and each column represents the category or cell where this observation falls. Thus, $x_{ij} = 1$ means that the $i$th object appeared in the $j$th cell and if $x_{ij} = 0$ it means taht the object did not appear. It is assumed that at least one entry of every row and every column will be one (the possibility of different objects being in different categories is OK). The matrices $A$ and $B$ are obtained by normalising the rows and columns of $X.$ That is, define
$$
x_{i \cdot} =\sum_{j = 1}^d x_{ij}, \quad x_{\cdot j} = \sum_{i = 1}^n x_{ij}
$$
and set $A = \mathrm{diag}(x_{i \cdot}),$ $B = \mathrm{diag}(x_{\cdot j}).$

I have made more than a few attemps without success but neither of these have really used the structure of the problem. For example, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $A^{-1} X B^{-1} X^\intercal$ then any eigenvector of $\lambda$ will satisfy $XB^{-1} X^\intercal = \lambda A v.$ It is tempting to multiply on the left by $v^\intercal$ and us the fact that boths sides are now weighted norms of $v.$ *This already shows that $\lambda \geq 0.$* But the algebra becomes messy and I could not see a path forward to show $\lambda \leq 1.$ On top of this, I am not really using the structure of $X, A$ and $B$ as I already mentioned.

A perhaps useful fact (that I have not been able to exploit) is that the vector $\mathbf{1}$ (full of ones) has eigenvalue 1 and any other eigenvector is orthogonal to this one!

If you have ideas, hints, know a reference or how to do it, I'd appreaciate the help.

Best regards, W.

Comment: I think you want to read about the eigenvalues of a substochastic matrix.  If I've followed the discussion, I think, but haven't confirmed, that the matrix $A^{-1} X B^{-1} X^\intercal$ will be substochastic, assuming all the original context.  (That general statement is untrue can be seen by multiplying $X$ by a sufficiently large constant.)

Comment: @saulspatz I thought so too for a second but it does not seem like it. I mean, any row can take any value between $1$ and $p;$ if you divide by $p$ I suppose you have a substochastic matrix by rows. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the particular case you have, it can be shown as follows.
For any matrix $\Lambda$ with eigenvalues $(\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_n)$, one can bound the spectral radius
$$
\rho(\Lambda):=\max\{|\lambda_1|,\dotsc,|\lambda_n|\}
$$
by any operator norm of $\Lambda$, that is, $\rho(\Lambda)\le\|\Lambda\|$.
These norms satisfy the inequality
$$\|\Lambda\Lambda'\|\le\|\Lambda\|\|\Lambda'\|.$$

I'll choose the norm
$$
\|\Lambda\|_\infty:=\max_i\sum_j|\Lambda_{ij}|,
$$
and let $\Lambda:=A^{-1}X$, $\Lambda':=B^{-1}X^\top$.

Note that we simply have
$$\Lambda_{ij}=\frac{X_{ij}}{\sum_{\ell=1}^d X_{i\ell}},\quad\Lambda'_{ij}=\frac{X_{ji}}{\sum_{\ell=1}^n X_{\ell i}}.$$
Hence, since all the entries are positive we have
$$\|\Lambda\|_\infty=\max_{i=1,\dotsc,d}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{X_{ij}}{\sum_{\ell=1}^n X_{i\ell}}=1,$$
and in the same way
$$\|\Lambda'\|_\infty=\max_{i=1,\dotsc,n}\sum_{j=1}^d\frac{X_{ji}}{\sum_{\ell=1}^d X_{\ell i}}=1.$$

Therefore, all eigenvalues must lie in the interval $[-1,1]$. Since you already showed that they must be non-negative, they actually all lie in $[0,1]$.

The general case is not true as pointed out by [saulspatz](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/235128/saulspatz) in one of the [comments above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4198339/show-the-eigenvalues-of-a-square-matrix-are-between-zero-and-one/4198385#comment8709866_4198339).

Comment: I'm not following the argument that $\rho(\Lambda) \leq \| \Lambda \|$ by _any_ operator norm. Is this really true? I would not think so. Any norm can be rescaled and it will remain a norm, so we can rescale the original operator norm by $\varepsilon \rho(\Lambda)$ and it will still be an operator norm, but the inequality will no longer be true if $\varepsilon > 0$ is small enough. You do seem to use this property to use the $\| \cdot \|_\infty$ as opposed to the usual (canonical) operator norm. (I really want this argument to work, tough. It is quite _elegant._)

Comment: I think you used the term "operator norm" to mean a norm such that $\|MN\| \leq \|M\|\|N\|.$

Comment: @WillM.: I used operator norm to mean any _induced operator norm_ on matrices, as in [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms). They are all indeed submultiplicative.

Comment: I read that yesterday. Thanks a lot. I am very surprised about the “depth” of math that is needed for this exercise considering it comes from a statistics book for not very technically oriented audiences. I am wondering if the authors had envisaged a different proof from the reader.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question at the beginning of your post is clearly negative: when $A$ is unrelated to $B$ and $X$, as long as $X\ne0$, if we put $A=tI$, the spectral radius of $A^{-1}XBX^\top$ will approach infinity when $t\to0^+$.

In the specific case where $A$ and $B$ are positive definite, $A^{-1}X$ is row-stochastic and $XB$ is column-stochastic, the product $S=A^{-1}XBX^\top$ will be row stochastic. Hence its spectral radius is $1$, as shown in the other answer. (More succinctly, it's because $\rho(S)\le\|S\|_\infty=1$, where $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ denotes the induced supremum norm.) Since $S$ is similar to the positive semidefinite matrix $A^{-1/2}XBX^\top A^{-1/2}$, its eigenvalues are also nonnegative. Therefore they all lie inside the real interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: I am not fully convinced the other answer shows the spectral radius is 1. On top of this, I am not acquainted at all with this concept. Never read about it, never heard it until now, and you both are probably using easy facts about it but I am totally lost in both arguments.

Comment: @WillM. All *submultiplicative* matrix norms (including *induced* norms in particular) are bounded below by the spectral radius. This is well-known and its proof is easy. Let $\|\cdot\|$ be any submultiplicative norm, $(\lambda,v)$ be any eigenpair of an $n\times n$ matrix $S$, and $M$ be the matrix whose $n$ columns are all equal to $v$. Then $|\lambda|\|M\|=\|\lambda M\|=\|SM\|\le\|S\|\|M\|$. Since $v$ is an eigenvector, $M$ and $\|M\|$ are nonzero. Cancel out $\|M\|$ on both sides, we get $|\lambda|\le\|S\|$. This is true for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $S$. Hence $\rho(S)\le\|S\|$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that clarifies a lot. Yeah, I read Wikipedia article yesterday and Duck duck go several resources for spectral radius. As a matter of fact, I took one course on that topic back in 2010 when doing my 3rd year in bachelor's and never saw the topic again and totally forgot about everything. I did take and even taught Markov chain courses but there showing that a vector of 1s is eigenvector is trivial and do not need spectral radii. I like both answers but I'll respect chronological order.